# Is this the place to ask questions about animation software like blender, synfig, maya, 3Ds max?

Tags: discussion

I've seen that there is a dedicated site about blender, but there is more 2D and 3D animation software like synfig studio, maya, 3Ds max, sketchup, blender, …

2D drawing software: inkscape, gimp, photoshop, illustrator.

Is this the community for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not if you're asking questions about **using** software like that. This site would only be relevant if your question is about how to **write** such software.

This site is for questions about computer graphics algorithms and research.